# Failed to Select data with query builder

Tags: php, yii2, query-builder

I Want to select data from 2 tables with query builder yii framework. SO my script is below

```
$result = $command->select( array('a.parameter_name', 'a.unit', 'b.result', 'b.normal_value'))
                ->from('parameter a')
                ->join('test b', 'a.parameter_id = b.parameter_id')
                ->where('b.noRM='.$_POST['no_rm'])
                ->queryAll();
```

When I `echo` the result, I only get `parameter_id`.

```
foreach($result as $row){
   $name = $row['parameter_name'];
   $unit = $row['unit'];
   $normal_value = $row['normal_value'];
}
```

I get this error.

> Error 500
>
> Undefined index: parameter_name.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show full method

Comment: May be you need to call `$command->reset()` before creating new query. This method availble since v1.1.16

Answer (score 0):

Both `array` or string in `select()` will work, but use `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()` in place of `$command` variable, as `$command` hold old `CDbConnection`object which you are using for select and insert.

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('a.parameter_name, a.unit, b.result, b.normal_value')
                ->from('parameter a')
                ->join('test b', 'a.parameter_id = b.parameter_id')
                ->where('b.noRM='.$_POST['no_rm'])
                ->queryAll();
```

Comment: there is no `parameter_id` in select, can you check again `$result` variable not getting override?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97921/discussion-between-chetan-ameta-and-diyah).

Comment: `$command may have old executed query in memory` - it's not true

Comment: @SiZE according to @Diyah question, $command is an object of CDbConnection, she was inserting some value and then retriving some value from same object, that is why she is getting wrong result. Just because `$command` hold same object, that is why i wrote this line

Answer (score 0):

try using alias for resolving the column name (the same name you use in array key)

```
 $result = $command->select('a.parameter_name as parameter_name, 
                a.unit as unit, 
                b.result as result, 
                b.normal_value as normal_value')
            ->from('parameter a')
            ->join('test b', 'a.parameter_id = b.parameter_id')
            ->where('b.noRM='.$_POST['no_rm'])
            ->queryAll();
```